# Infinite loop while building mergesort in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mergesort

I'm attempting to build out a monkey-patched version of `mergeSort` but I'm running into errors every single time. I've ran through debugger a few times and it looks like everything is sorting properly until the last step where I jump to a line in a **loader.js** file.

Can anyone help me check this out? Thanks in advance!

```
Array.prototype.mergeSort = function(callback) {
    if (this.length <= 1) return this;

    if (!callback) {
        callback = function(x, y) {
            if (x > y) return -1;
            else if (x < y) return 1;
            else return 0;
        };
    }

    const mid = Math.floor(this.length / 2);
    const sortedLeft = this.slice(0, mid).mergeSort(callback);
    const sortedRight = this.slice(mid).mergeSort(callback);

    return sortedLeft.merge(sortedRight, callback);
};

Array.prototype.merge = function(arr, callback) {
    let merged = [];

    while (this.length > 0 || arr.length > 0) {
        if (callback(this[0], arr[0]) < 0) {
            merged.push(arr.shift());
            break;
        } else if (callback(this[0], arr[0]) >= 0) {
            merged.push(this.shift());
            break;
        }
    }

    merged = merged.concat(this);
    merged = merged.concat(arr);

    return merged;
};
```

Comment: Side note; your first `callback = ...` part is effectively the same as `return y - x;`

Comment: Second side note; `} else if (callback(this[0], arr[0]) >= 0) {` is just an else statement when paired with the first if.

Comment: Understood on both counts, cleaned it up a bit but still having issues for some reason.

Comment: @Taplar: not really, for example `return y - x` does not handle strings whereas the OP's default comparison function does.

Comment: @chqrlie if the values are string, subtraction isn't appropriate in the first place, and should be using the native `localeCompare` instead.

Comment: @Taplar: That's exactly my point: you say that the default comparison function is effectively the same as `return y - x;`, but the OP's function can be used to compare strings, hence to sort an array of strings in Unicode lexicographical order, whereas the subtraction is not appropriate for that and therefore is not *essentially the same*.

Comment: @Taplar: `String.prototype.localeCompare()` is an alternative, but strings can be compared with `<` and this comparison may be more appropriate in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merge loop should stop when **either** list is empty: instead of `while (this.length > 0 || arr.length > 0)` you should write:

```
while (this.length > 0 && arr.length > 0)
```

Furthermore you should not `break` from the loop after each store into the `merge` array, and it is redundant to compare the elements twice.

Here is a corrected version:

```
Array.prototype.merge = function(arr, callback) {
    let merged = [];

    while (this.length > 0 && arr.length > 0) {
        if (callback(this[0], arr[0]) < 0) {
            merged.push(arr.shift());
        } else {
            merged.push(this.shift());
        }
    }
    merged = merged.concat(this);
    return merged.concat(arr);
};
```

Note however that your `merge` method sorts the array in descending order and the default `callback` function compares the elements in descending order too, causing the array to be sorted in increasing order by coincidence. You might want to simplify this and accept a `null` callback function in `merge`.

Here is a more generic version:

```
Array.prototype.mergeSort = function(callback) {
    if (this.length <= 1)
        return this;

    const mid = this.length >> 1;
    const sortedLeft = this.slice(0, mid).mergeSort(callback);
    const sortedRight = this.slice(mid).mergeSort(callback);

    return sortedLeft.merge(sortedRight, callback);
};

Array.prototype.merge = function(arr, callback) {
    let merged = [];

    if (callback) {
        while (this.length > 0 && arr.length > 0) {
            if (callback(this[0], arr[0]) <= 0) {
                merged.push(this.shift());
            } else {
                merged.push(arr.shift());
            }
        }
    } else {
        while (this.length > 0 && arr.length > 0) {
            if (this[0] <= arr[0]) {
                merged.push(this.shift());
            } else {
                merged.push(arr.shift());
            }
        }
    }
    return merged.concat(this).concat(arr);
};
```